# Libpcap not capturing any interface on android device

Tags: android, packet, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am trying to make a packet sniffing `Application` and I had build it as a system `Application` for nexus 4.

```
r = pcap_findalldevs (&alldevs, errbuf);
printf("R==========%d",r);   

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag",errbuf );

error is E/Tag ( 4751): Can't open netlink socket 13:Permission denied
```

I cant capture any interface on my device. I have also given permissions to my application

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_RAW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
<permission-group android:name="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"></permission-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you logging an error?  To quote the `pcap_findalldevs()` man page:

```
RETURN VALUE
   pcap_findalldevs() returns 0 on success and -1 on failure.   If  -1  is
   returned,  errbuf  is  filled  in  with  an  appropriate error message.
   errbuf is assumed to be able to hold at least PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE chars.
```

If r is 0, no error occurred, and there is ***NO*** guarantee that `errbuf` contains *anything* meaningful.  Do

```
if (pcap_findalldevs (&alldevs, errbuf) == -1)
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Tag",errbuf );
```

instead.

Comment: could you please suggest any solution to avoid this error? Thanks in advanse

Comment: What error?  Unless `pcap_findalldevs()` returns -1, there is no error.  Did you change your code to do what I said it should do - i.e., *check the return value of `pcap_findalldevs()` and print an error message only when it returns -1*, and then run it, and did it then print an error?